# How can I add an image to the back of a CALayer after rotate 90 degrees?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-animation

I want to add a back image to a CALayer when the my rotation transform degree is higher than 90.

It is just like a Flipboard flip animation.

This is my current code:

```
 CALayer *layer = self.view.layer;

 int frames = 130;

 layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);

 CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
 transform.m34 = 1.0 / -2000.0;
 transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -frames * M_PI / 180.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

 self.view.layer.transform = transform;

 CAKeyframeAnimation *pivot = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

 NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:45];
 NSMutableArray *times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:45];

 for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++) {

  CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
  transform.m34 = 1.0 / -2000.0;
  transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, -M_PI / 180.0 * i, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

  [values addObject:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
  [times addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)i / (frames - 1)]];
 }

 pivot.values = values;
 pivot.keyTimes = times;

 [values release];
 [times release];

 pivot.duration = 0.5f;
 pivot.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;

 [layer addAnimation: pivot forKey: @"pivot"];
```

Could anyone tell me how to add a back image just like the flip effect.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the easiest way to do it is to add two sublayers representing the front side and the back side of the page. Set both the sublayers' `doubleSided` property to NO. Set the back side layer transform to the same flipped transform you're animating to. Then, when the page's front side faces the viewer, the front side layer is visible and the back side layer is "hidden", and vice versa.

See [GeekGameBoard](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GeekGameBoard/Introduction/Intro.html) source code (Card.m) for a sample of the technique.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I ended up animating two layers at the same time, and the back layer would automatically come to front when the degree was higher than 90. I didn't touch the doubleSided property. Thank you all the same.